# Trying to Explain Objects

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented

After a year hiatus from Computer Science courses in college, im back to hitting them hard for the next two years straight. In the next few weeks before classes start again I have been trying to refresh my memory on key concepts by writing and trying to explain them to people that have never gotten deeper into a computer than Word, or Excel, maybe even just Photoshop.

Right now i'm trying to explain Objects and Classes, using the cookie cutter is a class and a cookie is an object.

In trying to explain Objects I thought that starting with trying to describe a Cookie would be easy and I described it like so.

```
Dinosaur_Cookie_Name = "T-Rex"
Dinosaur_Cookie_Frosting_Colour = "Green" 
Dinosaur_Cookie_Eaten = False
```

And then I was going to explain how these have no linking between them and that if you wanted to say that

```
my_cookie = Dinosaur_Cookie_Name
```

it doesn't necessarily mean that it's also green and uneaten.

So I was then going to explain that by making `my_cookie` a list, you could then iterate through the list to access properties and tada, a sort of rudimentary object. Afterwards would then be, tada here is what an object is.

That's where I froze. In the year since learning about Objects in my beginning C++ class I couldn't remember how I made the jump TO Objects. 
I remember a little talk about name spaces and pointers but thats about it.

So do objects store properties in an array? 
Would it be appropriate in teaching about Objects to have a middle step of a list, between non-associated variables and an object?

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts and implementation issues in an unhelpful way.

Answer (score 1):

**Car**

My favourite explanation of objects/classes is centered at cars.

---

**Class**

Class is defined as a **schematic** of information you can "measure from" or "store in" a car instance. 
For example, every car has a color, production date, total distance passed, etc.

---

**Object**

Objects are "real" or "existant" things made upon a class (schematic). All the cars consist of properties such as color and distance traveled, but the actual values of these properties may vary.

---

**Implementation**

Object implementation may differ between languages and compilers, but I guess this might be a good way to do it:

Calculate space needed for all subobjects/properties (pointers/ints/strings/other objects) which reside in the object itself. On object creation, take up **precalculated memory**. 
Functions inside classes (methods) are no different than "normal" functions, it is just that compiler enforces them to be called **on object** or **inside of** fashion due to object-oriented programming philosophy.

When you try to get/set certain property of an objects, compiler actually translates it into **memory offset** from start of objects memory, so yes, you couldsay it acts like array with different data types in it.